# Django responds to options request despite the lack of Authorisation token

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm testing responses from a rest api.  If a user does not send a token, I expect that a 403 response will be sent.

In the test (below) I create a user, create and grab their auth token (for use in other tests) and test if i can send an options request with no authentication.

When testing the endpoint with an external request, i get the response:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

But my code is returning status 200 with the response to the options request.

I've checked that nowhere in the code i `force_authentication(...`, and `self.client.credentials.__dict__)` returns a blank dictionary.

Why is django returning the request when `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`?

View:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
class getUserOptions(views.APIView, ReturnMetadata):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def options(self, request):
        field_meta = self.user_metadata(request)
        return Response(field_meta)
```

Test:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class basic_functionality(APITestCase, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user_details = {...}
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user_model = get_user_model()

        user = self.user_model.objects.create(username=self.user_details['username'])
        user.set_password(self.user_details['password'])

        user.first_name = self.user_details['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.user_details['last_name']
        user.email = self.user_details['email']
        ...
        user.is_active = self.user_details['is_active']
        user.save()

        self.client.force_login(user)

        user_temp = self.user_model.objects.get(username=self.user_details['username'])
        self.user_token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user_temp)[0]

class user_options(basic_functionality):

    def request_user_options(self, payload):
        """
        Test getting options for the user form
        called by test_user_options
        payload: 
            - Authorization : token
        """
        url = reverse('user_options')
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        response = self.client.options(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

        return response

    def test_user_options_bad_token(self):
        payload = {}
        response = self.request_user_options(payload)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `force_login` gives you a session in your `APIClient`, meaning theat you don't have to authenticate subsequent requests.  This is not what i personally was looking to achieve, as it's not the experience a user with my authentication settings would need.

I had to set `self.client.force_authenticate(user=None)`

From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/):

> Login:
>   The login method functions exactly as it does with Django's regular Client
>   class. This allows you to authenticate requests against any views which include SessionAuthentication.
>
> ```
> # Make all requests in the context of a logged in session.
> client = APIClient()
> client.login(username='lauren', password='secret')
> ```
>
> Unauthenticate:
>
> To unauthenticate subsequent requests, call force_authenticate 
>   setting the user and/or token to None.
>
> ```
> client.force_authenticate(user=None)
> ```